# "classList.add" doesn't add a class to a div and a form elements

Tags: javascript, css, class, dom

I currently stumbled upon trouble with the inability to add a class to div/form elements via classList.add method.
The same very method works perfectly for other elements like input or button.
However, no magic happens with the div and the form.

Please, ignore that the JS code is linked externally within the HTML.
Here all that matters that these two lines don't work:

```
form.classList.add = "formList";
buttonWrapper.classList.add = "buttonContainer";
```

```js
(function(){
  function formCreation () {
   //Here I add elements"
    let container = document.createElement('div');
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    let buttonWrapper= document.createElement('div');
    let buttonCreator = document.createElement('button');
    let buttonRemover = document.createElement('button');

    input.placeholder = 'Enter your new task';
    buttonRemover.textContent = 'Delete'
    buttonCreator.textContent = 'Add';

    //Here I'm trying to add classess//
    form.classList.add = "form";
    //It won't work for the form'
    buttonWrapper.classList.add = "buttonContainer";
    //Neither it would work for the buttonWraper div"
    input.classList.add('input');
    buttonCreator.classList.add('creator');
    buttonRemover.classList.add('remover')


    container.append(form);
    buttonWrapper.append(buttonCreator);
    buttonWrapper.append(buttonRemover);
    form.append(input);
    form.append(buttonWrapper);
    
    return {
      form,
      input,
      buttonCreator,
    };
  }

 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let containerApp = document.getElementById('container');

    let heading = createAppTitle('Things to be done');
    let todoItem = formCreation();
    let listItself = todoListCreator();

    containerApp.append(heading);
    containerApp.append(todoItem.form);
    containerApp.append(listItself);

  });

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="container"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a method that you need to call, not a setter that you have to assign to. Look at the other usages of the method in your code where you did it correctly (e.g. `buttonCreator.classList.add('creator');`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand how this code would work on any element type.

The format:

```
form.classList.add = "formList";
buttonWrapper.classList.add = "buttonContainer";
```

is wrong.

Try

```
form.classList.add("formList");
buttonWrapper.classList.add("buttonContainer");
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for info on using classList and its properties.

Comment: Might be a (2) typo(s) or might be a misunderstanding.

Comment: In the lines right after they wrote it correctly though…